# Write log files while unit testing static library (not an app)?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, file-io, static-libraries, xctest

Where can I write files in such a case? No app documents directory as there is no app eventually. Can I write OSX filesystem somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yap, can write to iOS Simulator Library.

```
NSString *library = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
[dictionary.description writeToFile:[library stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dictionary.dictionary"] atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
[assertation.description writeToFile:[library stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"assertation.dictionary"] atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```